# “The Gaussian elimination” or “Gaussian elimination”?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, nouns

I have seen it used without a quantifier in my textbook, but I don’t see how it doesn’t need one.

Some example sentences:

The LU factorization leads to another perspective on Gaussian elimination.

It is no more efficient to use this than to use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: It all depends on context. Without context, there is no answer.

Comment: @oerkelens State some examples of when each form is appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, but if you want an answer, it is up to you to provide some context. Why don't you include some examples in your question and explain your doubts about them?

Comment: @oerkelens here you go.

Comment: Those two example sentences seem fine. Can you explain why you think they would need an article?

Comment: This may be a question that needs to be answered, not with a general rule, but with a case-by-case enquiry into naming conventions.  For example, the Wikipedia page [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) refers to “The Gaussian elimination algorithm” (attributive noun?) and “The Gaussian elimination” one time each, but says “Gaussian elimination” (without an article) over a dozen times.  (One of its source documents, [Gaussian elimination - math-linux.com](https://math-linux.com/mathematics/linear-systems/article/gaussian-elimination), … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  has a mixture of “Gaussian elimination” and “the Gaussian elimination” — but I suspect that the latter are really shorthand for “the Gaussian elimination *process*”, or something similar.)  But, on a hunch, I looked at [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis).  It begins, “In mathematics, the Riemann hypothesis is a conjecture that the Riemann zeta function has …”, and uses the definite article for both “Riemann hypothesis” and “Riemann zeta function” almost without exception. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  For more examples, see [List of scientific laws named after people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scientific_laws_named_after_people) and [List of things named after Carl Friedrich Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Carl_Friedrich_Gauss). … You might be able to get a better answer at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Scott Turn that into an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would prefer one of your examples to say "*LU factorization leads to another perspective on Gaussian elimination*" with no need for articles in either case unless we are referring to a specific case.

Whoever wrote the Wikipedia piece on [lower-upper decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=LU_decomposition&oldid=865402665) seems to have taken a different view, putting several definite articles in front of *LU decomposition* where I would not.

For *Gaussian elimination*, the same piece did not use definite articles for the noun (e.g. "rather than using Gaussian elimination each time", but does for "the Gaussian elimination process" and "The Gaussian elimination algorithm".  I think this is a good approach, and [I have now done the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=LU_decomposition&diff=867057145&oldid=865402665) with *LU factorization* or *LU decomposition*.